# (Laravel & SQL) Alternative method for setting foreign key cheks in seeders situation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

To prevent *"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot **truncate** a table referenced in a foreign key constraint.."* when running DatabaseSeeder(.php) method run(), I set foreign key checks to 0, then call table seeders, and after that set foreign key checks again to 1. I feel like this isn't the best thing to do here, so I'd like to know what's the best syntax solution (if *this* isn't):

```
public function run()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

    $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to delete the objects referenced in foreign key constraints first.

Comment: where/how? at least directions :)

Comment: Do your deletes in the opposite order.